# Bootstrap data toggle tab activate bootply libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

First of all, it's my first post and I'm still kinda newbie but I'm keen on learning more and more.

[I checked out this before I decided to ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750482/data-toggle-tab-activating-second-tab-on-page-load) because I kinda got stucked.

So here is example of the code:

http://www.bootply.com/C1Xu5M0RnP

It works how I wanted it to do so but if I put it into my code and trying to test it locally I got some problems. Switching tabs by clicking on tabs work perfect, but when I try to click on the link which should move me to another tab it doesn't do so. I see the link + '#profile' or '#home' but tab and content don't show.

I don't have any errors at console debug. I included scripts in a way, a lot of people suggested here - jquery first, bootstrap after.

The question is what am I doing wrong or what libraries are preloaded on bootply?
I would be really grateful for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it works now. The problem was that I was using my own script first, then I was loading jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: its ok to accept your own answer. you should so that people know the question has been answered